# Android client to .NET WEB API How to do it?

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

I did example using .Net Web Api where I post a different requests from .Net Client to Web Api Server. And I am trying to do a similar client for Android. But it Did not work! Can anyone help me, where I wrong?
This is one of my method in WEB API Server

```
public Book GetProduct(int id)           
{
    Book item = repository.Get(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return item;
}
```

So I Want to do a get requset from Android APP

```
    private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

    private static final String TAG = "HttpGetTask";

    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:2757/api/book/1";
    AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
        JSONResponseHandler responseHandler = new JSONResponseHandler();
        try {
            return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Who can do a simple example for Android how I can do a get request to WEB API Server? I didn't find anything in the internet... I mean how to do requests to ASP.NET WEB API...

Answer (score 0):

I created selfhosting for web api application (just google web api self hosting). For example I did it like console application. After I found my IP in ipconfig, and wrote my IP-address in place of localhost. And after I conncted my phone to the same wi-fi and it works!